# How would traditional Judaism categorize the general time location of the prophets?

Tags: navi-prophets

Assuming the following four categories, is this how **traditional** Judaism would group the prophets?

The prophets of the northern kingdom (Israel):

- Hosea
- Amos
- Jonah

The prophets of the southern kingdom (Judah):

- Obadiah
- Joel (Some 'modern scholars' date Joel in post-exile)
- Isaiah (Some 'modern scholars' date parts in post-exile)
- Micah
- Nahum
- Jeremiah
- Zephaniah
- Habakkuk

Prophets during Exile:

- Ezekiel
- Daniel

Post-exilic prophets:

- Haggai
- Zechariah
- Malachi

I know Samuel, Elijah, Elisha, etc... may pre-date these categories, I'm not sure how they would be grouped.

**NB:** I am assuming this is not a controversial question, i.e. the answer is either "Yes", or "no, because blah". I am hoping asking what the "traditional" view is will eliminate the modern tendency for "scholars" to come up with endless debates on these types of things. Thanks.

Comment: So you're assuming those are the categories to use and asking only whether the list for each category is correct? Or you are asking also whether those are the categories Judaism would use

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most of your grouping is uncontroversial.  It seems like your question is more like "Do any Orthodox rabbis agree with the "modern" dating of Joel and parts of Isaiah?"  Is this a correct interpretation of your intent?

Comment: One that would need to be moved is Obadiah. Jewish tradition identifies him as Ahab's chief of staff of that name, mentioned in 1 Kings chapter 18, which makes him a northerner.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that this might be partially unclear. Yes, I'm mainly wondering about Joel and Jonah. I didn't know there was a question mark over Obadiah either.

Comment: Also I don't care about modern atheist dating methods. Tradition is sufficient for me.